# What does '/bin/bash: line 2: 30063 Killed' mean?

Tags: compiling, android

I'm trying to install ps2dev a homebrew playstation 2 development toolchain and SDK But I'm having trouble compiling gcc 11.1.0 it stops at

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/david/ps2toolchain-ee/build/gcc/build-mips64r5900el-ps2-elf-stage1/gcc'
build/genautomata ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/mips/mips.md \ insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
/bin/bash: line 2: 16577 Killed 
build/genautomata ../../gcc/common.md ../../gcc/config/mips/mips.md insn-conditions.md > tmp-automata.c
make[2]: *** [Makefile:2459: s-automata] Error 137
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/david/ps2toolchain-ee/build/gcc/build-mips64r5900el-ps2-elf-stage1/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:4410: all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/david/ps2toolchain-ee/build/gcc/build-mips64r5900el-ps2-elf-stage1'
```

I'm quite litterally using my android phone running a linux emulator called UserLAnd running debian/ubuntu

**Android Version**
*8.1.0* (Oreo)
**Model**
*Alcatel TCL LX A502DL*
**Chipset**
Mediatek *MT6739WM*
**CPU**
*4x ARM Cortex-A53 @ 1105 MHz (1.1 GHz)*
**GPU**
**PowerVR GE8100**
**Instruction Set**
*64-bit ARMv8-A (32-bit Mode)*
**RAM**
*2GB*
**Internal Storage**
*16GB*

Comment: Use code formatting for command output, please: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code

Comment: The output posted is not clear where each line begins and ends. Please correct that so it is more clear, and we can see which part of what is associated with which line.

Comment: An Android phone is not a common development environment. It has an Arm CPU, and you may be trying to use a package that bootstraps the compiler from an Intel binary. Or you may be running out of RAM: compiling GCC is pretty demanding and 2GB is extremely small by the standards of compiling a compiler. Try a PC, even a slow one, but one with a decent amount of RAM.

Comment: I'm trying todo is compile the GCC for ps2dev's homebrew toolchain for the "EE" Emotion Engine which is MIPS-based with a modified instruction. mips64el r5900 and it compiled the older version of GCC compiler.

Answer (score 3):

`/bin/bash: line 2: 16577 Killed` Means that the process with the PID 16577 got killed.  A bash script ran this process, and the OS Killed it independently for some reason.

> “Killed” indicates a SIGKILL, which can be generated by the kernel.
> One possible reason is if the process tries to go over a resource
> limit, or possibly if the system runs out of memory. It could also be
> something that UserLand generates for whatever reason, perhaps because
> the process is trying to use a system feature that UserLand doesn't
> provide. When attempting to compile GCC with only 2GB of RAM, the OOM
> killer (triggered by running out of RAM) is plausible.

Some of the possible reasons are listed by Gilles 'SO - stop being evil'

Comment: “Killed” indicates a SIGKILL, which can be generated by the kernel. One possible reason is if the process tries to go over a resource limit, or possibly if the system runs out of memory. It could also be something that UserLAnd generates for whatever reason, perhaps because the process is trying to use a system feature that UserLAnd doesn't provide. When attempting to compile GCC with only 2GB of RAM, the OOM killer (triggered by running out of RAM) is plausible.